heat and high battery consumption on ThinkPad T14s Gen 3 AMD
I recently bought a ThinkPad T14s Gen 3 with an AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 6650U and installed Ubuntu 24.04. It works great but the fans are constantly running and the processor is generating a pretty good amount of heat, even while idle with no applications open. Obviously, this takes a toll on the battery. Looking at the Gnome system monitor, CPU usage is almost nothing. I don't know much about tuning processors and don't think that would usually even be necessary. The OS is fully updated, as well as the laptop firmware. Does anyone know of anything I could do to get this under control? This isn't a cutting edge laptop- it's at least three years old, so I can't imagine that I would need to be using a rolling distro to properly utilize it. Any thoughts?

Are you sure it's CPU and not GPU?  GPUs can generate a lot of heat, even idling on a screen.  Most laptops don't have independent cooling from CPU and GPU.

It very well could be- not sure how I'd know that or what I'd do about it. Ubuntu is not offering any additional drivers to download and so I assume that the kernal would already have what it needs to manage the GPU. Is there some other utility I should be using?

Check out https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-gpu-monitoring-and-diagnostic-commands/ where you can find several ways to get GPU measurements. And nvtopcould be the tool for you.
